# Using Microsoft Graph API in a daemon

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a daemon that uses the Graph API to populate items into a shared Outlook calendar. I have created an app at apps.dev.microsoft.com, given it Graph permissions (Delegated User.Read, Directory.Read.All, User.Read.All) and App perms (Calendars.ReadWrite, Directory.Read.All, User.Read.All), and generated a secret.

Our Azure admin has gone through the Admin Consent process, and validated that an AAD ServicePrincipal has been created.

In the following code, graphClient gets created but when I try to use it (to list users here) I get the exception Authorization_IdentityNotFound, "The identity of the calling application could not be established". What am I missing?

I have used the same clientID in an interactive authentication flow example successfully, so the app setup in AAD appears to be OK.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace CCSync
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string ClientId = "e914fd5d-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private static string ClientSecret = "...";
        private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;    

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {                
            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await GetUsersAsync();    

        }


        public static async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync()
        {
            var graphClient = GetGraphClient();

            try
            {
                var group = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
                if (group == null) return null;
                return group;
            }
            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient()
        {
            // get access token including application permissions
            ConfidentialClientApplication cl = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            ClientId,

              "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token",
              new ClientCredential(ClientSecret),
              new TokenCache(), null);
            AuthenticationResult authResult = cl.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(
              new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).Result;

            if (graphClient == null)
            {
                // Create Microsoft Graph client.
                try
                {
                    graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {
                                var token = authResult.AccessToken;
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);


                            }));
                    return graphClient;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            { return graphClient; }

        }
    }
}
```